# asp.net couldn't make my form to be a table

Tags: c#, css, asp.net

I have here a simple web form

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1"  runat="server" >
    <div class="row">
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Name: "/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="NameTextBox" runat="server"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Address: "/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="AddressTextBox" runat="server"/>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Mobile No.: "/>
        <asp:TextBox ID="MobileTextBox" runat="server"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I was watching EJMedia tutorial regarding css, and he created this css and converted the form into a table.

```
#form1 
{
    color: white;
    display: table;
    background-color: teal;
    border: solid 2px black;
}

.row {
    display: table-row;
}

.row label {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
    color: white;
}

.row textarea {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

EDITED:

```
.row input{
        display: table-cell;
        padding: 2px;
    }
```

but the problem is, the form did not aligned itself just like what it did in the demo. EJMedia was using plain html while I use asp controls. Is there a way to align my simple form using css or do I have to go back to table tr td tags which make it a little unreadable?

Comment: Unless those TextBox controls are multi-line, they should be generating `<input />` elements, not `<textarea>`. Are you using any other CSS in this project (`row` is a class in Bootstrap, for instance)?

Comment: no i dont. actually, that was previously .row input{} but then I tried textarea coz it didn't work

Comment: is any css link used in EJMedia? check it in header.

Comment: EJMedia? yes there is in the header. I just want to figure out whether his method of not using table tr td tags is possible to asp.net controls or should I revert to using table tr td tags.